# php md5 hash function returning a 500 internal error

Tags: php, hash, error-handling, md5

I am trying to create a md5 hash for a string but the problem is that whenever I use md5 function and run the file, it returns a 500 internal error.

the code i am using is

```
$php_hash_string = md5("test_hash");
```

When I comment out the file the error is not produced and the rest of the output is printed out but when i use the md5 function it generates 500 internal server error.

Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Server info: LAMP on CentOS 5.6

Comment: Check your PHP error log. According to [this ServerFault answer](http://superuser.com/questions/147975/how-can-i-get-log-messages-from-the-lamp-server-on-ubuntu-10-04) it is at `/var/log/apache2/error.log` in the default LAMP installation.

Comment: I have, nothing there. Absolutely nothing...I am shocked...

Comment: How about [this fix](http://www.commondork.com/2010/05/21/how-to-display-php-errors-on-your-lampwamp-setup/)? That should make the error(s) display in the browser.

Comment: doesn't fix this...Absolutely frustrating

Comment: Have you tried to leave only '<?php $php_hash_string = md5("test_hash"); echo $php_hash_string;' in you file? Have you tried to execute it in console (on linux systems it is like php -r 'echo md5("test_hash");')? If you are using this string later in the script - it may be something other that breaks your script. Also, try to completely retyping that line as somethimes when using copy/paste some bad characters are copied as well that are not visible in IDE, but still cause problems.

Comment: make a separate test.php containing only this line: `<?php $php_hash_string = md5("test_hash"); ?>` does that give you the error too?

Comment: yes, i have tried the simplest methods and reinstalled php, changed php versions, but this error is not going away....I am very frustrated. :(

Comment: Did you try hash('md5','test_hash') (or other hash algorithms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make sure that you do yum install php-mcrypt and see if that makes a difference

Comment: thanks, just reinstalled the whole php and solved the prblem. apparently md5 was corrypted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you want to use this way, but at least try it.

```
$md5 = md5("test_hash");
$php_hash_string = $md5;
```

It's probably just stupid try, but mostly only stupid things make problems.

And put in top of the file this:

```
error_reporting (E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE);
```

Comment: How can this help? Only thing you do - double hash the string.

Comment: like i said its stupid try but sometimes even stupid tries can solve the problem.

and i forgot to remove md5 from the second one, i edited the comment

Answer (score 1):

> the code i am using is
>   $php_hash_string = md5("test_hash");
>   When I comment out the file the error is not produced and the rest of the output is printed

So that's not the code you are using, only a part of it.

The first step is to confirm that it really is the md5() call which is causing the problem. Do you still get problems with a script containing **only** that one statement?

> it returns a 500 internal error.

Have you verified that your installation is correctly configured to report/log PHP errors? And that it is **not** logging errors when executing the md5 function? And there is nothing related to this logged by the webserver? e.g. try:

```
<?php
 for (
?>
```

(this should produce a fatal parsing error)